# Typescript angular error : Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I want to parse a json local file with a service component, but I get the error `Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined` when I am trying to get the json, even though I don't use toLowerCase.

Here is my service function to get my data :

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { Card } from './card';
import { MessageService } from './messages/message.service';
import {search} from "../assets/search.json"

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CardService {
  private cardsUrl = 'api/cards';  // URL to web api

  constructor(
     private http: HttpClient,
     private messageService: MessageService) { }

  getCards(): Observable<Card[]>{
    const url =search;
    var datas =  this.http.get<Card[]>(url);


    console.log('data : '+datas);
    return datas;

  }
}
```

I am trying to get an array of type Card[] with this function.
The console log shows `data : [object Object]`. 
And if I print `console.log('data : '+datas[1]);`, it prints `undefined` for `datas[1]`.
My Card object :

```js
export class Set{
  code: string;
  name: string;
  type: string;
  block: string;
  image: string;
  rareNumber: number;
  uncommonNumber: number;
  commonNumber: number;
  landNumber: number;
  marketingNumber: number;
  releaseDate: number[];
}
export class Card {
  nameEnglish1: string;
  nameFrench1: string;
  nameEnglish2: string;
  nameFrench2: string;
  manaCost: string;
  cmc: number;
  colors: string[];
  colorIdentity: string[];
  type: string;

  //set here
  set: Set;

  textEnglish: string;
  textFrench: string;
  flavorEnglish: string;
  artist: string;
  number: number;
  power: string;
  toughness: string;
  loyalty: string;
  layout: string;
  multiverseidEnglish: number;
  multiverseidFrench: number;
  imageUrlEnglish: string;
  imageUrlFrench: string;
  rulings: string[];
  originalTextEnglish: string;
  originalType: string[];
  variations: string[];
  mtgid: string;

}
```

EDIT :

And I get my datas like this in a component :

```js
  getCards(): void{
    this.card_service.getCards()
      .subscribe(cards => this.cards = cards);
  }
```

EDIT2 html code to display data :

```html
<div class="card_container">
    <mc-search-bar></mc-search-bar>

      <div class="row no-gutters table-wrapper-scroll-y card_grid">
            <div *ngFor="let card of cards" class="col-sm-2">
                <img [src]="card.picture_url" class="rounded grid_space" [alt]="card.name"
                    data-toggle="popover-hover"  data-placement="top">
            </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try console.log(datas);

Comment: It prints `Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}`

Comment: its an Observable, subscribe to it to get the value

Comment: @ZulHuky Did you use Custom `pipe` or Built-in `pipe` anywhere in the code?

Comment: @ZulHuky show the HTML Code or Stackblitz if possible?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale I was using it but not anymore. I updated my post with the html code (I don't know what Stackblitz is)

Comment: @ZulHuky Unable to reproduce [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-svog1t)

Comment: Change your `getCards(): Observable<Card[]>` to `getCards(): Observable<any>` and `var datas =  this.http.get<any>(url);` and report the output, I honestly can't reproduce you problem. You could also use `type` or `interface` instead of `class` to declare your (I'm guessing here) types.

Answer (score 3):

You should move datas inside subscribe like this

```
getCards(): Observable<Card[]>{
    const url =search;
    this.http.get<Card[]>(url).subscribe(data=>{
       console.log('data : '+data);
       return data;
   });
}
```

or use like this

```
getCards(): Observable<Card[]>{
    const url =search;
    return  this.http.get<Card[]>(url)
}
```

And in your component use

```
this.cardService.getCards().subscribe(data =>{
    this.datas = data;
})
```

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned it, but I already did the subscribe things. I edited my post